Glenn Gould version of Eroica?
I cannot find it anywhere
Did Glenn Gould ever record Liszt-Beethoven symphony 3, Eroica?
I have found the 4th mvmt by GG but what I actually want to check out is the 1st mvmt...
Could anyone help me out please? Thank you so much in advance

If you have found the 4th movement, then why wouldn't the 1st exist?

@Joachim: I fail to recognize, why recordings have to be complete. Wikipedia lists  nothing in respect to Eroica.

:'( because of the significant popularity of the 4th maybe?

Glen Gould never recorded anything more than the fourth movement of Beethoven's Third Symphony.  It's not unusual for musicians to record only a part of a symphony.  It's easier, it's more fun, not everyone wants to sit through a whole symphony, and some parts are more popular than others.  Liszt's transcriptions of Beethoven's Symphonies for piano are very challenging to play.  Learning one of them well enough to make a commercial recording is a big commitment.  Gould recorded the Fifth and the Sixth in their entirety, and a pile of variations on the fourth movement of the Third.  Gould enjoyed playing his own variations and he apparently liked this tune.  If he had recorded the complete Third, it wouldn't be hard to find at all.
https://glenngould.com/music/beethoven-variations-for-piano/
